# How to make responsive image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, slider

I have a simple responsive image slider, which works almost fine but the problem is when the image changes from one image to another image, has a big jump, I want to solve this problem. please, see the code. and help me. thanks.

```js
$("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();

$("#slideshow")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#slideshow > li:first")
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo("#slideshow");
    }, 3000);
  })
  .mouseleave();
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <ul id="slideshow">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/800/300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `position: absolute` your `LI` elements inside a `position: relative` parent.

```js
var timer; /* P.S: forgot about this??? */

$("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();

$("#slideshow")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    if (timer) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#slideshow > li:first")
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo("#slideshow");
    }, 3000);
  })
  .mouseleave();
```

```css
* {margin: 0;}


#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 300px;
}

#slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#slideshow li img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <ul id="slideshow">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/800/300" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

That code above was someone's idea I've seen a lot here on SO which I totally **dislike**. Modifying the DOM appending elements (useless relayout/repainting)... targeting non cached elements... etc...

**My suggestion** is to simply use a counter and a far better approach

```js
/* FADE GALLERY */
(function() {

  var $slides = $("#slideshow").find("li"),
    tot = $slides.length,
    c = 0,
    itv;

  function anim() {
    $slides.stop().fadeOut().eq(++c % tot).fadeIn();
  }

  function play() {
    itv = setInterval(anim, 3000);
  }

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(itv);
  }

  $("#slideshow").hover(stop, play).mouseout();

}());
```

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

#slideshow li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slideshow li + li  { /* Hide using CSS to prevent flickering */
  display: none; 
}

#slideshow li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <ul id="slideshow">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/0bf?text=0" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/f0b?text=1" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/ff0?text=2" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/0fb?text=3" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```